# What state of function arguments does debug_backtrace() capture?

Tags: php, debugging, debug-backtrace

Some abstract code:

```
function test($a = 5) {
  debug_backtrace();
  a = 10;
}
```

What will debug_trace tell us about arguments of the test function?
Will it capture `$a` as 5 or 10?

Comment: I don't think you know what "pseudo code" means.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, thanks, my fail.. Hope "abstract" will be more suitable for this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we call the function from the example this way:

```
test(4);
```

it'll capture '4'.

And if we call it this way:

```
test();
```

it'll capture actually no data about the arguments. I suppose parser doesn't initialize arguments if they haven't been used anywhere. (Calling debug_backtrace doesn't count.)
I've done some more researches and things have turned out a little bit unexpected (personally for me) if passing arguments by reference... But logical enough, I admit.
If we use the following code:

```
<?php
    function test2(&$a) {
            $a = 5;
            test($a);
            $a = 8;
    }
    function test(&$a) {
            $a = 6;
            print_r(debug_backtrace());
            $a = 7;
    }
    $test = 1;
    test2($test);
```

We'll get such output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [file] => /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.php
    [line] => 4
    [function] => test
    [args] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) 
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [file] => /var/www/localhost/htdocs/index.php
    [line] => 13
    [function] => test2
    [args] => Array ( [0] => 6 ) 
  ) 
)
```

So debug_backtrace() always prints current state of function arguments passed by references (when debug_backtrace() was actually called), no matter if they had another value on a parent function call.
Be careful when debugging! :)

Comment: How do you debug the debugging?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, ehm, excuse me?